# What do I use, CherryPy or Pylons?

Tags: python, pylons, cherrypy

Hi I'm planning on building a site with social networking features. Which Python framework do you think is more appropriate or you would suggest over the other, CherryPy or Pylons?

Comment: With no actual requirements, it's a coin toss.  This is too vague to answer.

Comment: There are more python frameworks available than only the two mentioned; why the restriction?

Answer (score 3):

That's a subjective question. I suggest you read carefully each framework's description and choose the one that has the most features fitting your project.

Here's an extensive [overview of the two frameworks](http://old.nabble.com/Pylons-vs-CherryPy-td25693132.html). This should help you choose the right tool for your project.

Comment: Disagree:  the question isn't "subjective", it's "completely vague" or perhaps "too vague to have a rational answer".

Answer (score 2):

As S.Lott said it is vague, so best way would be to toss a coin, and I did
head=pylons
tails=cherrypy

but on toss it came standing up, so

[django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) it is.

and a django based platorm is [pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/), quoted from the site

> While our initial development was
>   focused around a demo social
>   networking site, Pinax is suitable for
>   a wide variety of websites. We are
>   working on number of editions tailored
>   to intranets, event management,
>   learning management, software project
>   management and more.